# Updating the URL in the address bar for a fade in overlay div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have the code below which fades in/out a div for a contact page. I would like this page to have its own URL so when users type that into the address bar, the page loads up with the div already activated. Also, if possible, I would like it so when users click 'back' or 'forward' on their browsers, this page behaves like how a regular page would meaning the history is kept intact.

How should I go about applying this feature to what I already have?

```
var c = 0;
var contactHeight = $('#contact-keebs').outerHeight();

function contactFadeIn() {
    $('#contact-keebs').fadeIn(200);
    $('body').css({
        height   : contactHeight,
        overflow : 'hidden'
    });
    $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
}

function contactFadeOut() {
    $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
    $('body').css({
        height   : '',
        overflow : ''
    });
    $('#contact-keebs').fadeOut(200);
}

$('#mail-wrap').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

        $('#contact-button').addClass('project-button').css('width', '71px').text('Projects');
        $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-projects.png');
        $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop : 0
            },200, contactFadeIn);
        } else {
            contactFadeIn();
        }

    } else {

        $('#contact-button').removeClass('project-button').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch');
        $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-contact.png');
        $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop : 0
            },200, contactFadeOut);
        } else {
            contactFadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the `#` anchor in your url. Stack Overflow does it the same way. When you click upon an answer or question link where you participated it opens the page and the `#` part of the url loads the page to the anchor part that is defined in the html. You can have JavaScript check the querystring of the url and perform the fade in or out. That url will be cached into the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAY HELP USING API PUSHSTATE ?.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history